# Device screen size scaling in Apportable

Tags: apportable

I'm trying to convert an iphone app that consists of 3 different asset sizes for three different screen sizes (base-iphone(320x480), mid-iphone(640x960) ipad(768x1024),high-ipad3) into one for android that utilizes these different assets based on the resolution of different devices.

The code utilizes the ipad/iphone Idioms and apportable overrides the UIDevice methods for this using the VerdeConfigIsTablet() method. It is very unclear how this is done. Is there any good resource to understand how each resolution is assigned and scaled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [the Apportable UIScreen docs](http://docs.apportable.com/uikit-extensions.html#uiscreen).

Also, potentially useful is [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]:

```
(gdb) p  [UIScreen mainScreen]
$2 = (struct objc_object *) 0x6acd5490
(gdb) p [$2 bounds]
$3 = {origin = {x = 0, y = 0}, size = {width = 800, height = 1205}}
```